# PL/SQL - Let the variable behave as source code

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql

I have a stored procedure in which I need to "switching" between 2 names of schemas.
Here is an example:

```
declare
  schema1 varchar2(16) := 'left';
  schema2 varchar2(16) := 'right';
begin
  if (some condition) then
    select * from ???schema1???.tbl1 where id = 1;
  else
    select * from ???schema2???.tbl1 where id = 1;
  end if;
end;
```

How can I let **the value** of variable (e.g. `schema1`) behave as a part of source code? I mean that the code will be understood as:

```
...
  select * from left.tbl1 where id = 1;
else
  select * from right.tbl1 where id = 1;
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to go with dynamic sql if you want to use variable for schema reference, which would like this:

```
declare

schema1 varchar2(16) := 'left';
schema2 varchar2(16) := 'right';
myVar varchar2(100);

begin

  if (some condition) then
    execute immediate 'select * from ' || schema1 || '.tbl1 where id = 1' into myVar;
  else
    execute immediate 'select * from ' || schema2 || '.tbl1 where id = 1' into myVar;
  end if;

end;
```

Comment: Yes, `execute immediate` is what I need. Many thanks.
Shortik